# isteven-multi-select output model not working with templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using isteven-multi-select in my application for multiple selection. Everything works fine until I add isteven-multi-select div in another template. In that case, I dont get any values in output-model.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ObnmcALS18nviW6qWf7P?p=preview)

Here , I am addding it in another template

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-include="'test.html'"></div>
   <button ng-click="a()">Print output</button>
   <p>selected scope: {{ selectedScope }}</p>
</body>
```

test.html --

```
 <section>
  <div>
    <div isteven-multi-select
        input-model="scopes"
        output-model="selectedScope"
        button-label="name"
        item-label="name"
        tick-property="ticked"
    >
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ng-include` creates new scope that inherits all parents scope properties. So you should pass parents `selectedScope` to `output-model` attribute:

```
<section>
   <div>
        <div isteven-multi-select
            input-model="scopes"
            output-model="$parent.selectedScope"
            button-label="name"
            item-label="name"
            tick-property="ticked"
        >
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

You can read [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for better understanding of scopes.

Answer (score 0):

it works once you include the element in your main controller view

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.21"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-multi-select.css" />
    <script src="angular-multi-select.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <section>
   <div>
        <div isteven-multi-select
            input-model="scopes"
            output-model="selectedScope"
            button-label="name"
            item-label="name"
            tick-property="ticked"
        >
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    <button ng-click="a()">Print output</button>
    <p>selected scope: {{ selectedScope }}</p>
    <p>selected scope: {{ scopes }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 456 said: "Everything works fine until I add isteven-multi-select div in another template." I think he wants to make it work with `ng-include`.